# check connection with ssh2 functions in PHP

Tags: php, ssh, sftp

I need to check the connection with the function http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php

But if I made a check like this

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('myserver.com', 22);         
if (!$connection){
    echo 'no connection';
}else{
    echo 'connection ok';
}
```

I never get into the line " echo 'no connection'; "

Can you explain me why?
And how to make a check like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your server. Try to connect to some non-existing one and see what happens.

If you need to check only connection, then you can use something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php also

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you should use the functions like `ssh2_auth_password`, or `ssh2_auth_public_key_file` and combine with `ssh2_connect function` to check whether the connection is authenticated or not

```php
    $connection = ssh2_connect("myserver.com", 22);

    if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, "username", "password")) {
      echo "connection is authenticated";
    }
    else {
      echo "failed!";
    }
```

Hope this helps!

edit: missing semicolon

Comment: how can i find out what my username is ?

Comment: the username and password are often provided by the sysadmin if you have one of them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the 4th parameter `$callbacks` could yield some feedback on this problem.

The issue is likely due to inability to connect (Duh). This could be because a firewall, no internet, heavy security on SSH. Try calling `# ssh -v <host>` on PHP box to see what the problem could be.

Comment: Is not a problem that the server do not connect.
I want to write the case that the server can't connect.
I've already tried the 4th parameter $callbacks but it doesn't works...

Answer (score -1):

Yet another example of why [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/), is better than PECL's ssh2 extension.