# How to connect to Linux using PHP?

Tags: php, linux, authentication, ssh

I am working on a game-server hosting panel and I've been tried this:

```
        $ssh = ssh2_connect('xx.xx.xx.xx', 22);
        if(ssh2_auth_password($ssh, 'user', 'userpass'))
        {
            echo 'Success';
        }
        else
        {
            die('Fail');
        }
```

But its just doesn't show any message (Success/Fail).
How can I make this connection work? ><

Comment: make sure the ``PECL`` extension ``ssh2``is installed

Comment: possible duplicate of [check connection with ssh2 functions in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197368/check-connection-with-ssh2-functions-in-php)

Comment: I am pretty sure I have these PECL & ssh2, but how can I make sure it is installed?

Comment: @Ran `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` or from command line `$ php -i | grep ssh2` .. should show you something like `libssh2 version => 1.2.8`

Comment: I did, and I got: libssh2 => 1.4.2

Answer (score 1):

you probably do not have the libssh2 extension installed. it is a pretty big pain to install it so i will recommend you use this tool:

https://github.com/phpseclib/libssh2-compatibility-layer

include it  at top of file and all your libssh2 function calls should work even if libssh2 is not installed.